# String passed in parameter

Tags: java, jna

I'am a little problem with the JNA.

My code :

header c :

```
#ifndef IOPROTOCOL_H_INCLUDED
#define IOPROTOCOL_H_INCLUDED

typedef signed char INT8;
typedef short       INT16;
typedef int         INT32;
typedef unsigned char  UINT8;
typedef unsigned short UINT16;
typedef unsigned int   UINT32;

/* Types d'IO */
typedef enum { IOT_U1, IOT_U2, IOT_U8, IOT_I8, IOT_U16, IOT_I16, IOT_U32, IOT_I32, IOT_F32, IOT_STRING, IOT_MAX } IoTypeE;

typedef union {
    INT32  i;
    UINT32 u;
    float  f;
    char * s;
} Value;

typedef struct {
    int (*Read) (char *rxbuf, int rxlen, UINT8 interTo);
    int (*Write) (char *txbuf,int txlen);
    int (*FunctionResponse) (int address, Value value, IoTypeE type);
    int (*SendTraceRoute) (char * trace);
} DeviceFuncT;


    int readTrame( DeviceFuncT *deviceFunct, UINT32 function, UINT32 address, UINT32 countAddress, UINT32 slave, UINT32 type);
    int writeTrame(DeviceFuncT *deviceFunct, UINT32 function, UINT32 address, Value value, UINT32 type, UINT32 slave);


#endif // IOPROTOCOL_H_INCLUDED
```

DeviceFuncT is created in Java and is passed in parameter in the function readTrame or writeTrame.

I call in C(since dll ^^) DeviceFuncT->(*Read) (char *rxbuf, int rxlen, UINT8 interTo);

In java,

```
 public static interface ReadFunct extends com.sun.jna.Callback{
        int invoke(String rxbuf, int rxlen, byte interto);
    }
```

So `char* rxbuf == String rxbu`f

I must handle rxbuf in Java before to finish the function and after, I handle rxbux en C but I don't arrive to have the value set in Java in the function  in C...

Can you help in this problem?  please :).

Sorry for my explication.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should only use `String` when your native type is `const char *` (a read-only C string).  If your native type is actually a buffer to which the native side writes, you need to use a primitive array, `com.sun.jna.Memory`, or an NIO direct buffer when calling native code from Java, and `Pointer` when receiving data from native code in a callback.

Since you're using this in a callback, the parameter needs to be of type `Pointer`.  You can then use the various `Pointer` access methods to read or write from the memory.

You can't use a primitive array or `java.nio.Buffer` in the callback, since the native code cannot construct those objects, and `String` is inappropriate because you cannot change the contents of a Java `String`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to change the parameter in java, this passes a String. You have to change the code in c to receive String without pointer.

```
Int invoke (String rxbuf, int rxlen, int byte) {
Char Newrxbuf [200];
    Strcpy (Newrxbuf, rxbuf.t_str ());
}
```

`.t_str()` applies to builder c ++ 2010 but can convert a string to `char *` in other versions of c